# Rmarkdown: Html in pdf document (plotly) or Html output size a4

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm new with `R-mardkdown`. I always use `pdf` output but I have a problem now. When I put `plotly` graph my `rmarkdown` doesn't work. I tried to add `always_allow_html:yes` but it don't work for me.

Maybe I can use HTML format but I need my output will be A4 size.

---

```
   title: "R"
    author: "Liguang"
    date: "January 2019"
    output:
     pdf_document:
     always_allow_html: yes
     documentclass: article
     classoption: a4paper
```

I don't find a reference about it. plus I don't know why can't work always_allow_html.

Anyone could help?

thanks!

Comment: You need to transform your interactive chart into a static one. You have to use the `webshot` package. take a look at [this](https://kahaaga.com/posts/2018-02-18-rmarkdown-embedding-plotly-graphs-in-pdf-outputs/) page.

Comment: @patL is there possible to  adjust the size of the html page to A4?

Comment: I don't know. Once you have changed you graphs to statics, you can use output it as PDF and use A4 format.

Comment: @patL yeah I tried but I would like interactive graph. Thanks.